# Evaluate JavaScript in QTP

Tags: javascript, qtp

Is there a way to evaluate a JavaScript function on a webpage in QTP, assigning the result to a QTP variable.

I'm using QTP version 9.0.

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://www.softwareinquisition.com/-p=81.htm

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you want to put that in a formal answer so you can reap the points?

Comment: @Aaron your link is broken. Now it's http://www.softwareinquisition.com/81.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the link supplied by [@Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215030/aaron) this functionality is built in to QTP 11 as `Page.RunScript` and `Frame.RunScript`, QTP 9.0 is pretty old would you consider upgrading?

Comment: Thanks. I believe the customer is planning an upgrade soon but in the meantime I'm stuck with 9.0. Such is life.